# unattached (disconnect) Core Data entity from context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using magical record for all my core data work.

everything works great, with the exception at times when I'm doing updates in the background I need to detach or disconnect the entity from the context.

for example

```
ButtonList = [Buttons MR_findAllSortedBy:@"listOrder" ascending:YES];
```

How would I keep the entity, but remove the reference to the context for the array ButtonList?

Thanks

Comment: `MR_findAllSortedBy` returns an `NSArray`. An `NSArray` is not and can not be associated with a managed object context. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: The button entities which is in the Buttonlist array (the entity has properties like buttonname, buttonicon, etc.) will have its properties become nil when data is being delete and updated in the background.  It's like it's still referenced to core data.  So these buttons are displayed on a tableview and when the user is scrolling it populates the table cell names with the button names.  these will become blank when the entity int he background is deleted.  I need it to not have any references to the core data after a fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only happen when you don't use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, or code that observe context changes and remove deleted objects from the UI to reflect the store state.

If you like the deleted objects to be removed from view as soon as your context finds out about the deletion, you would need to listen for "context did change notification" on your main context and look at the deleted objects set, if any of the deleted objects are part of your display array you will need to update your view accordingly (remove from array and update table. a `NSFetchedResultsController` also listen for context changes).

Another option:

Since you manage your tableview state by yourself (and not a fetched results controller) and
If you like the "buttons" to remain in view including their properties, you could:

Change your request to return dictionaries instead of managed objects (does not nullify on deletion):

```
NSFetchRequest* r = [Buttons MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"listOrder" ascending:YES];
[r setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

//This is your link to the data store and managed object (if you later need to fetch by or update if still exist)
NSExpressionDescription* objectIdDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription new] autorelease];
objectIdDesc.name = @"objectID";
objectIdDesc.expression = [NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject];
objectIdDesc.expressionResultType = NSObjectIDAttributeType;

[r setPropertiesToFetch:@[objectIdDesc,@"buttonName",@"buttonIcon"/*, and any other property you need for display*/]];
```

Now all is left to do is execute this request on any context you like (even in background) and get the array back to your table view controller.

The difference here is you get back dictionaries and not `NSManagedObject` array.

Answer (score 0):

In Core Data there's no such concept of "detaching" an entity from a given context. You would have tons of problems in attempting to do something like that (e.g. move objects between contexts/persistent stores), especially when dealing with relationships.

I think you should refactor and design your application in a way that reacts proactively to any changes in the object(s) you are representing, e.g by removing the related table view cells (with NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate callbacks), by automatically popping the detail view controller if present, etc...

I would not recommended recommend it but, if there are states for the object you're representing which are "transitory" and shouldn't be reflected in the UI, you could temporarily nil the NSFetchedResultsController delegate (I assume you're using that to display your managed objects) so that it doesn't receive updates and doesn't update the table view (for example). When the objects are ready to be displayed again, you can set the delegate back and perform a new fetch, so that the tableView gets updated (with automatic cell insertions, removals and updates).

Answer (score 0):

If an object has been fetched from a managed object context, the only way to break its connection to the context is to delete the object and then save changes. There is no way to convert a fetched object into something that's not associated with its context. You could copy the data to some other object, but the one that you fetched is and will always be associated with the context that you got it from.

In your case, if you're deleting these objects in a background queue, *you should not be using them any more*. Or if you do need to use them, then *you should not be deleting them*. I can't tell from your question just what you're trying to accomplish here, but what you've described makes no sense.